# OrientDB exclude certain vertices from traverse

Tags: orientdb

I want to be able to exclude certain vertices from an OrientDB traverse query.

For example,

```
traverse * from (select from Location where ID = '1234')
```

will traverse all vertex classes at a starting point. I need a way to add exclusions for specific classes.

I know this could be possible if I didn't use the `*` operator and instead specify all of the classes I do want. However, it would not be suitable because there will be classes my program isn't even aware of. The data is ever changing but the classes to exclude will always be present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly.

I have this structure.

[image]

I want to traverse starting from the node A1 excluding node of class B and the related branch.

I use this query

```
traverse * from #12:0 while @class<>"B"
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I use this query

```
select * from (traverse * from #12:0 while @class<>"B") where @class<>"E" or (@class="E" and in.@class<>"B")
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

```
select * from (traverse * from #12:0 while @class<>"B") where @this instanceof 'V' or (@this instanceof 'E' and in.@class<>"B")
```

Comment: This is great! However, it still returns dangling edges. Can we exclude those too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `difference()` function:

```
select expand($c)
let $a=traverse * from (select from Location where ID = '1234')
$b=select from <class to exclude>
$c=difference($a,$b)
```

not sure about the synthax, but it should work

Bye, Ivan